# Load and replace old content

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to use load and replace old content in div, in my case after I use AJAX I get new content and old content both inside div.

My Ajax code is

```
$('#vu').on("click", function(e){
    $.ajax({
    url: 'url to page',
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function() {
          $('#vp').load('url to load');
        }               
    });
});
```

My HTML div

```
<li><a id='vu'> <?= $total_up ?> </a></li>
<div id='vp'> OLD CONTENT </div>
```

What I'm getting now as result is

```
<div id='vp'> NEW Content  OLD CONTENT </div>
```

But I want to get only new content like

```
<div id='vp'> NEW Content </div>
```

Comment: You could potentially `$('#vp').empty().load('url to load')`

Comment: still the same nothing changed I tried with use only empty but seems empty not working

Answer (score 0):

You must clean the previous content with:

```
$("#vp").html(""); or $("#vp").empty();
```

and then you can load the new content. With your code:

```
$('#vu').on("click", function(e){
    $.ajax({
    url: 'url to page',
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function(){
          $('#vp').html("");
        },
        success: function() {
          $('#vp').load('url to load');
        }               
    });
});
```